# Can anyone find out an counter example to this unitary statement?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $A$ and $B$ are unitary, then $A+B$ is not unitary.

I think this statement is true .

I tried to find out counter example but I failed.

Answer (score 2):

The $0 \times 0$ matrix is unitary, thus it is a counterexample.

Exluding degenerate matrices, $1 \times 1$ matrices are the simplest; they're usually a good place to look for counterexamples, if you aren't trying to exploit noncommutativity.

A $1 \times 1$ unitary matrix is simply a complex number of absolute value $1$. So the question becomes, can you find three complex numbers of absolute value $1$ such that $x+y=z$?

(if you have trouble with this, try thinking what this would mean geometrically)